# Word Docx mailmerge using xml data and merging using xslt OPENXML

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word, openxml, mailmerge

I have been searching the net all day to find an answer with no luck; maybe someone has a simple answer for me?

I have created a Word Docx from which I have extracted the word/document.xml to create an xslt file.

I have literally no experience so this is a very steep learning curve so I have been following various examples which I have found and have produced a working 'mailmerge' or transformation using data which is generated from SQLServer as XML.

I now need to do the usual 'mailmerge' stuff like ignoring any blank lines in the address which is printed at the top of the page but I have no idea how I can do this using my xslt file, or any other method for that matter.

Looking at the xslt file, one example of a 'paragraph' which should be ignored is:

```
          <w:p w:rsidR="0067165E" w:rsidRPr="00F841C2" w:rsidRDefault="0067165E">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
            <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00F841C2">
          <w:rPr>
            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
            <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address2"/>
          </w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
```

as I don't want to print a blank line if Address2 is not populated.

From what I have read and the little that I understand (and probably misunderstood), I need to set up functionality to ignore nodes which contain no data (Have I got that much right?)

Can I use this?

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>
```

and how does that interact with the

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
```

which I have already put at the top of my xslt file?

If anyone can help me out on this, it would really help to move me along.
Sorry if it is so simple that I should be able to do it with my eyes closed but I've got to start somewhere!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that I was probably trying to see the most difficult way to do something really simple. I have had another look at this and answered my own question by simply using  on the element and enclosing the whole section.

Thanks to anyone who might have taken the time to look at this, sorry to have asked such a dumb question!